# Why I get this random weird number C++

Tags: c++

I am new to using pointers with c++, so I am trying this small code but the problem is that when i try to print **name** i get this random weird number  `\364\277\357\376\326\241+\310\364\277\357\376\310`. This is not the memory address, which is confusing and what confuses me more that when i replace **name** with **getName()** it works perfectly and prints the name! Thanks you!!

**Person.cpp**

```
#include "Pesron.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Person:: Person()
   {

   }
  Person::Person(string Name, int Age)
   {
       name=&Name;
       age=Age;

   }
   void Person:: setName(string Name)
   {
       name=&Name;
   }

   void Person:: setAge(int Age)
   {
       age=Age;
   }

   string Person:: getName()
   {
       return *name;
   }
   int Person:: getAge()
   {
       return age;
   }
void Person:: display()
{
    cout<<*name<<" "<<age<<" ";
}

Person::~Person()
{

}
```

**Student.cpp**

```
#include "Student.hpp"

 Student:: Student(string Name, int  Age,int Grades, int ID):Person(Name , Age)
{
    grades=Grades;
    id=ID;
}
 void Student:: setId(int ID)
{
    id=ID;
}
  int Student:: getId()
{
    return id;
}
  void Student:: setGrades(int Grades )
{
    grades= Grades;
}
  int Student:: getGrades()
{
    return grades;
}
void Student:: display()
{
    Person::display();
    cout<<grades<<" "<<id<<endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Pesron.hpp"
#include "Student.hpp"
#include "graduteStudent.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    Student student("ZAID",21,2211,11);
    student.display();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
\364\277\357\376\326\241+\310\364\277\357\376\310 21 2211 11
```

Comment: Read [a good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and the documentation of your compiler and your debugger. If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with all warnings and debug info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Prefer [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) and standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)

Comment: Be also aware of the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html)

Comment: The fact that using `getName()` works is very unfortunate and confusing. It probably has to do with the position of the stackpointer so the dangling pointer happens to point to "right place". That doesn't matter, it is undefined behavior and should be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Person::name` looks like it is a `std::string *`. In `Person::Person(string Name, int Age)` you pass the paramater `Name` by value and then store the address of this *local* variable in `name`. When `Name` goes out of scope you have a dangling pointer.

(This also applies to `void Person::setName(string Name)`)

Dereferencing `Person::name` is undefined behaviour, because the object it is pointing doesn't exist anymore. The solution is to simply store a `std::string` and not just a pointer to it.

So you get something like

```
class Person {
  private:
    std::string name;
    int age;

  public:
    Person(std::string Name, int Age) : name(Name), age(Age) {}
};
```